# Definite article in middle of Hauptsatz

Tags: relative-clause, definite-article, relative-pronoun

> Entstanden ist der Teufelsberg nämlich ab 1950 aus den Stücken der im Zweiten Weltkrieg zerbombten Berliner Häuser.

What roles does "der" play in the above sentence? I would say it is a relative pronoun but normally for relative, it comes in Nebensatz with the idea mentioned first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the article for "Häuser" (genitive plural: *der Häuser*). The extended attribute "im Zweiten Weltkrieg zerbombten" and the attribute "Berliner" separate it from the noun it belongs to.

Shortened version of the sentence:

> Entstanden ist der Teufelsberg aus den Stücken der Häuser.

Comment: Thank for your assistance. The ans made me realize this is exactly same question I asked a few months back.

Comment: Thank you for linking to that question, @DavidVogt 's answer there is really nice.